# How to get the list of Database versios in Goolgle cloud sqladmin API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to fetch list of available database versions using google cloud sqladmin API in python.
I am not able to figure endpoint to be used.
[Here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/connect) is rest api doc link.

Can you please guide me how to get solve this?